# How to create "IE-like" new session window in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, google-chrome-extensions, internet-explorer-8

Like we can open a **New Session** Window in IE 8 or greater, can do the same in Google Chrome?

I know that Google Chrome has New incognito Window feature but by using it, we can open Max 2 sessions at a time.

If we have a normal window with its session and an incognito window with its session, we cannot open other windows with "New Session".

I have gone through these superuser.com questions [How can I get a new browser session when opening a new tab or window on Firefox/Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/690/how-can-i-get-a-new-browser-session-when-opening-a-new-tab-or-window-on-firefox) and [Firefox / Google Chrome plugin to enable multi-session browsing](https://superuser.com/questions/264138/firefox-google-chrome-plugin-to-enable-multi-session-browsing).

I tried with both of them but no success. I have tried to install that [Extension](https://superuser.com/questions/264138/firefox-google-chrome-plugin-to-enable-multi-session-browsing), given in second question link, in Google Chrome but it's even not able to open New Google Chrome instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with IE8. Assume you are using Windows.

Open `cmd.exe`

```
cd C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=the
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=quick
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=brown
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=fox
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=jumps
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=over
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=lazy
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=dog
```

Each of those would launch a new profile.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain more about your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Goto Click on your account at chrome and go to Manage People

[image]

Comment: ... and then what?

Comment: Add Person or Browse as Guest it's up to you